# javascript function "createCallback" called >50 times when I use addClass/removeClass in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, jquery-ui, firefox

I'm working on a web app in ASP.NET 2.0 that involves several `GridView` elements.  When users click one of the rows in a grid, that row needs to show its selection by changing color.  Each row has attributes set to identify its record type and unique ID:

```
<tr data-elementType='myType' data-myID='12' onclick='selectionFunction();'></tr>
```

I accomplish the selection through a javascript `onclick` handler on each row that calls a function that:

- Removes the `selected` class from the previously selected row
- Adds the `selected` class to the new selected row
- Updates the value of a hidden field with the new selected unique ID so server-side code can know which element to perform an action on when a button is clicked (view, delete, etc).

One of these grids now has just over 700 records in it.  In Firefox 3.6, the selection operation on this grid is horribly slow (about two seconds); in other browsers (even IE 7 and 8) it's not a problem.  I put `console.log` statements at the start and end of the selection function, and in Firebug they show up very fast at the end of the delay, suggesting that it's not the selection function that is slowing things down.  I used the profiler in Firebug and it says that "`createCallback`", which is defined in one of the "ScriptResource" script files generated by ASP.NET, is taking the huge majority of the time.  What is `createCallback` and why does it seem to be so slow in Firefox 3.6?  Is it a bug in FF, or is it a problem I can solve?

**UPDATE**: I am, of course, using jQuery to add/remove classes from the rows.  I've been working with jQuery 1.5.2 and jQueryUI 1.8.11, but I updated to the latest (1.6.2 and 1.8.14 currently) to no avail.  I tried putting a breakpoint in `createCallback` to see where it's getting called, and when it breaks there it's several frames down in the call stack from my call to `removeClass`.  Here is what the stack looks like in Firebug:

`createCallback()` - in ScriptResource.axd?......

`wherever possible trim: trim ? function(text=" ")` - in jQuery

`removeClass(value="selectedRow")` - in jQuery

`removeClass(classNames="selectedRow", speed=undefined, easing=undefined, callback=undefined)` - in jQueryUI

`selectionFunction()` - in my .aspx page

`onclick`

I don't understand why jQuery is triggering an ASP.NET generated function like this.

**UPDATE 2**: some more investigation has provided some more detail.  It seems that this "createCallback" function is getting called A LOT when I use `addClass`/`removeClass`, and it's happening in both Firefox 3.6 and Firefox 5.  I found the same function in Chrome and put a breakpoint on it, and it's not getting called at all, so this seems to be a Firefox thing.  I put a breakpoint on the function/line in question and selected a row, and the breakpoint got it *57 times*.  Only the first two involved me calling `removeClass` and `addClass`; the rest had `createCallback` several times in the callstack, and sometimes `BeginRequestEventArgs` too.  I've noticed it getting called also when I mouseover other jQueryUI stuff on the page (tabs), when jQuery uses `addClass` and `removeClass`.  But why is it getting called so many times when I do work on tr elements?

I'm changing the title and tags to reflect the real issue.

**UPDATE 3**: `createCallback` is getting called about the same number of times whenever I select a row in any of the grids, even if it only has 6 rows in it.  But in that case it's not a performance problem, and the profiler shows it only taking about 30% of the execution time, while it's at least 80% when I profile selection on the larger table.  So `createCallback` seems to perform worse when it's used in the context of more stuff visible on the page.  But it still seems like jQuery shouldn't cause a call to `createCallback`, especially since I couldn't fine any references at all to it in Firebug's script search.  And it appears to only get called in Firefox!

Note also that all of these grids are on the same page, but only one is visible at once, because I'm using jQueryUI tabs.

**UPDATE 4**: I managed to get something similar up on jsFiddle as requested.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N3F9v/1/).  In Firebug, find `createCallback` and set a breakpoint (just below my click handler in the script, where it begins with `Function.__typeName = "Function"; Function.__class = true; Function.createCallback = function (b, a)` and reload the page.  I get a lot of calls to it.

Comment: Are you experiencing this in production or is this happening while your running your application in VS's debug mode? FF is very slow in the second scenario.

Comment: @Crunchy - This is on our test server as well as my local sandbox environment.  How would FF javascript performance be impacted by running off of the development server in debug mode?

Comment: I doubt it would. I thought you were referring to ASP's onClick.

Comment: @Crunchy - Updated to clarify

Answer (score 1):

I have very little knowledge of ASP however it sounds like your problem is purely client side.

Declaring on "onclick" event for each row is not the most sensible way to handle the rows being clicked. Especially when you get into the quantity of rows you're talking about (~700+).

A better way would be to add a click event handler to the table and figure out what is clicked when it happens. I have written an application where a similar size table is being handled and we're not seeing anything like the lag you're experiencing upon click. there may well be other factors causing your click events to slow down however I would still suggest something along the following lines is worth implementing in any case:

```
$(function(){
    var rowSelectedClass = 'rowSelectedClass';
    $('#myTableID').click(function(e){
        if(e.target.nodeName === 'TD'){
            var $tr = $(e.target).parent();
            $('tr.' + rowSelectedClass).removeClass(rowSelectedClass);
            $tr.addClass(rowSelectedClass);

            // ....
            // Do whatever else you want to do when the row is clicked
            // ....

        }
    });
}
```

A good article to take a look at which advocates this method (and a few other handy jQuery tips) can be found here: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#leverage-event-delegation

Also worth noting that if your table has rows added dynamically after the page is loaded then consider using `.live()` instead of `.click()`.

**UPDATE @ July 28th 2011 9AM**
Having taken a look at the source more closely, I think the supposed calls to "createCallback" are a red herring. The line within your original jsFiddle source which contains the "createCallback" function is actually a really long string (~90,000 characters) of javascript. I think the fact that "createCallback" is the first function within that string is misleading Firebug's profiler. When you profile your original page's load, there are 2261 calls and as you said, there appear to be lots to "createCallback"

I've "beautified" (hate that phrase) this long JS string via http://jsbeautifier.org/ to make it readable and re-added it to a jsFiddle page. You can see it here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KvpmE/1/show/. Now when you profile this page's load you'll see a similar number of calls (2267 - not sure what happened to the other 6!) but importantly not a single one to "createCallback".

I still can't offer any solution though because essentially I've been unable to re-create your original issue which was that there was a 2 second lag in Firefox 3.6 when clicking a row.

Is this still the problem you're having?

Could you try and see whether you can re-create the problem within the updated jsFiddle page?

Also try and add the de-minified JS to your page to see if it helps you track down the actual functions being called when the row is clicked and therefore where the lag is taking place.

Comment: I did this and it still has the same delay.

Comment: Can you setup a test scenario at http://jsfiddle.net so we can see the problem first hand?

Comment: I'll try, but this seems like the kind of thing that is dependent on some little needle-in-the-haystack environmental thing.

Comment: see Update 4 for the link to jsFiddle.

Comment: Struggling to re-create at the moment. Taking the jsFiddle content from the "Result" frame into it's own window and profiling the click of a row, there is no createCallback function being called. For clarity, when profiling only the click (i.e. In Firebug - pressing "Profile", clicking a row and the pressing "Profile" again) is returning 71 calls in total with no noticable lag in Firefox (or any other browser that I can see). Can you take a look and confirm whether you can re-create on this page: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N3F9v/1/show

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my Update 4.  In the jsFiddle example, clicking the row doesn't trigger the calls to createCallback.  But if you set a breakpoint on line 40 of the "show" javascript file in Firebug and reload the page, it gets hit a lot.  That was the closest I could come to reproducing it in this context.

Comment: Also, the lag is only present in Firefox 3.6 (and older, I guess).  Firefox 5 has enough of a js speed difference that it doesn't lag hardly at all, even though it's still doing the same calls to createCallback.

Comment: Interesting observation that Firebug is being deceived.  I haven't been able to recreate the exact issue because it appears to be a very environmental thing.  I would point you to an installation of the project so you could see the problem first hand, but it's not public yet.  Management is not ready to spend any more resources on this right now, but if it becomes more of a problem down the road we'll reopen the issue and I'll update this question.  If I don't get this solved by another answer before the bounty expires, it's yours.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Jefferson,

It really sounds to me like you're actually performing a postback without knowing it.  Have you set a breakpoint on the server side yet to see if something is inadvertently firing your update panel?  It really sounds like some kind of postback is happening that is requiring a reload of dependant scripts.

I say this because 1) the problem you're having makes absolutely no sense - you're 100% on the money with JQuery and the ASP.NET Client Framework not even knowing they're neighbors in this case, and 2) the BeginRequestEventArgs instantiation sounds like the PageRequestManager thinks it should be doing something in response to your triggers...  You could also try breaking out Fiddler and just doing a quick sanity check to make sure some update panel of yours isn't firing.  There should be no HTTP traffic during the ops you're describing.

Sorry if this is an absolutely useless post for you, but with all of the work you've gone through to troubleshoot the client side it can't hurt to set a server side breakpoint just to do a quick sanity check / occam's razor...

Good luck - happy coding.

B

Comment: Unlikely because the one `UpdatePanel` on the page is not involved with this, but I tried it anyway.  No HTTP traffic was observed whatsoever in Fiddler when I selected a row.  I even made sure I knew what to expect by triggering an `UpdatePanel` refresh elsewhere.  I feel like it's related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969326/function-createcallback-doesnt-pass-context-correctly-in-firefox) because it's only Firefox, but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

`Function.createCallback` is used a lot internally by Ajax Toolkit and maybe its being called within your code unintentionally too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409287.aspx.

Since this is browser dependent, I would check code paths that are executed based on a specific browser.

Another clue to look for is if you're having any Ajaxtoolkit components for the grid or its individual rows as that would explain the increase in number of calls with the increase in rows.

There is also `Type.createCallback` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397568.aspx) so if you have any `Type` related code or methods, I would check those.

Comment: The MSDN link doesn't go anywhere for me...did you mistype?

Comment: Missed an `x` at the end. Fixed now. :)